# Mule Managed file transfer synchronization

Tags: mule

I am looking for a solution that will involve tranferring Files across two SFTP locations. i have a requirement to move file from a dmz to a internal app server.

I have designed two flows. one that read file from dmz and moves to a quarantine zone. the second flow picks from from quar and moves to the app server. what are the recommendations from experts to create a event or sync based model to fir this requirement. I am seeing errors like no such file generating during poll when file size is larger and still in transfer .

please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for one software, I recommend GoAnyWhere, in the workflow you can automate a lot of options, like this one that you talk.

you can check at : goanywhere.com (Managed File Transfer - MFT)

ps. I'm not a vendor, I just made a POC for one problem that I had and I saw that this can help you.